# ModuleNotFound Error in python script but only when imported into a parent script

Tags: python, windows, numpy, anaconda

On a windows machine with Anaconda installed. Script B runs correctly and produces the correct result. Script B is called from a Windows console app.

When script A imports script B, script B fails with the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'".

When script B is passed directly to Python executable, script B works and executes without error. (I'm new to python) Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How do the headers of the files with the import statements look like?

Answer (score 0):

basteflp, thanks for your response. I managed to solve it. The module not found error was due to running the script outside of the a specific Anaconda environment. Running the script after loading the Anaconda environment resolved the error.